# How to stub out Date that is implicitly referenced by years.ago in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I know that I can stub out a method on `Date` like so:

```
allow(Date).to receive(:today).and_return Date.new(2015,11,10)
```

So now if within my spec the code calls `Date.today` I can be assured that it will return a Date object with the value of 11/10/2015.

I have a scope that utilizes `years.ago.to_date`.  The user specifies the *number* of years ago for the scope:  Ex: `5.years.ago`, `2.years.ago`.

I am trying to test this scope.  In order to do so I need to control the `Date` that `years.ago` is referencing.  For instance, I would always want the Date to be 1/1/2010.  This way I will know that `5.years.ago` will return 1/1/2005, and 2.years.ago would return 1/1/2008.

The issue is that I do not know what to stub out.  I do not know how to keep the Date consistent which `years.ago` uses.

Hopefully this makes sense.  I just need to control the Date that `years.ago` uses.  How can I stub that out?

I looked a bit at [ActiveSupport::Duration](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-ago), but I'm not sure if that is the right place to look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check [timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop)

Then in your tests, you could freeze the `date` to your desired value as follows:

```
describe "some set of tests to mock" do
  before do
    Timecop.freeze(2010, 1, 1)
  end

  after do
    Timecop.return
  end

  it "should do blah blah blah" do
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can usually control what Ruby and Rails use for the current time by stubbing `Time.now`:

```
allow(Time).to receive(:now).and_return(Time.local 2016, 9, 6, 16, 51)
```

That does work for `years.ago`.

If your code, or the framework code you use, uses both `Time.now` and `Date.today`, however, timecop is easier.

If you use timecop, be aware that it's easy to forget to `Timecop.return`, which can screw up subsequent tests. Prefer timecop's [safe mode](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop#timecopsafe_mode).